# How to describe a confusion matrix correctly

Tags: grammar, commas, conjunctions, expression-choice, science

In computer science, we a use a thing called *confusion matrix* for reporting results from supervised machine learning algorithms. It looks like this

[image]

The image was taken from [here](http://www.gepsoft.com/gepsoft/APS3KB/Chapter09/Section2/confusionmatrix.png).

I would like to refer to the elements TP, FN, FP, and TN. Would this sentence be correct?

> A confusion matrix shows the number of true and false positives and negatives.

or should it be

> A confusion matrix shows the number of true and false positives and the number of true and false negatives.

I think I could write it

> A confusion matrix shows the number of true positives, false positives, true negatives, and false negatives.

Anyway, I would like to know what is the shortest correct form of addressing all the elements.

Comment: All of these are fine with their barely distinguishable nuances. You're overthinking it; those sentences don't define a confusion matrix, there's a bit more to it. Forcing things into a single sentence will be limiting. (I don't think you should use your second sentence because it is too weak in its single application of distribution)

Answer (score 2):

I think the last version is the best but you should perhaps expand it to "A confusion matrix shows the number of true positives (TP), false positives (FP), true negatives (TN), and false negatives (FN)."

Comment: Yes, always best to be precise. Conciseness is important but secondary.

Comment: Agreed. This statement unambiguously conveys the fact that there are four categories, without forcing the reader to think of any other possible meanings.